# N-channel MOSFET with Vgs(th) 10-12V?

Tags: voltage, mosfet

I would like to use a MOSFET as a switch in a circuit but I can't find any with a threshold voltage of 10v or 12v. Why is this uncommon?

As information, There is less than 1mA needed to go through it. I just don't want it on if its less than 10V on the gate.

Almost everything I see has a Vgs(th) of 1-4 volts.

EDIT*** Here is my circuit

I'm trying to delay the voltage to the gate by 2ms or more so that the LED won't light for that amount of time.

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 2):

Just use a resistor potential divider circuit or even one with a zener in series with the gate. The zener voltage will have to be exceeded before any significant voltage is attained on the gate. If using a zener it's best to assume low impedances to drive the gate. For instance a 10V zener and a FET with 1V threshold would likely need something like 10k across the gate to ensure zener leakage currents don't create a "false" gate voltage due to high impedances.

Comment: Can you explain how the zener will act as the voltage increases? Or do you simply mean use a zener with reverse bias voltage of 10V so that the reverse leakage builds a potential on the gate?

Comment: With about 10k across the gate, the zener leakage might be (say) 10uA and this will naturally generate about a hundred mV on the gate ie not enough to switch it on - you'll need then to exceed the reverse zener voltage to start raising this towards a volt. Basically I'm proposing using the zener as a voltage subtractor.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works like a charm in simulation; Using the zener in series with a resistor to bleed current off. Ordered parts and hopefully it pans out.

Comment: Good luck dude.